# Problem with Visual studio to open the emulator

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

how to link the emulator of android studio with visual studio code?

I have tried to link it ,but there is no results.

Is there any process to deal with this problem and I have the latest version of both softwares of vscode and android studio.